# for loop using a raw music array android

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, media-player

I am currently trying to create a for loop in which it will play a raw file and when it's done, it will go on to the next sound file in the array. It is currently playing all files at once. Any suggestions as to how i could fix this? I think there might be a problem with the on completion listener, but not sure. Thanks.

my Code:

```
package com.example.mediatest;



    int[] myMusic = {R.raw.caralarm, R.raw.phonebusysignal, R.raw.phoneoffhook};



    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();



   for (int y =0; y<3; y++){
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[y]);
       mp.start();
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

       });
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create separate MediaPlayer objects, start the first and then in `onCompletion` start the next. For a solution that scales, try this instead:

```
int[] myMusic = {R.raw.caralarm, R.raw.phonebusysignal, R.raw.phoneoffhook};
int mCompleted = 0;

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[0]);

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mCompleted++;
        mp.reset();
        if (mCompleted < myMusic.length()) {
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myMusic[mCompleted]);
                if (afd != null) {
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    afd.close();
                    mp.prepare();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // report a crash
            }
        } else {
            // done with media player
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
});

mp.start();
```

A simpler approach (slightly more wasteful of resources) is:

```
int[] myMusic = {R.raw.caralarm, R.raw.phonebusysignal, R.raw.phoneoffhook};
int mNext;
OnCompletionListener mListener = new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();
        startNextFile();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // usual onCreate stuff here, then...

    // either here or whenever you want to start the sequence
    mNext = 0;
    startNextFile();
}

void startNextFile() {
    if (mNext < myMusic.length) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[mNext++]);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(mListener);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested by get an error at the `MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(this, myMusic[0]);` with "The constructor MediaPlayer(mediatest, int) is undefined". I worked it around but still no success. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry. That should have been `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[0]);`. I'll fix the code.

Comment: Im slightly confused at to the order of the code you suggested because I'm getting errors of "cannot resolve to a variable". And did you mean `public void startNextFile(){`?

Comment: What line give the error? `startNextFile` doesn't _need_ to be public; it's not going to be called from outside the package. (You could even declare it private, although that would force the compiler to generate an access function so it could be called from the inner class method `onCompletion`.)

Comment: `mNext`, `myMusic`, and `mListener` inside the `startNextFile`

Comment: Ah. Those variables should be fields in the class that also contains the `startNextFile` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is working code for playing songs in continue loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private int[] tracks = {R.raw.explosion,R.raw.pianothingy_one,R.raw.car_horn_x};
int mCompleted = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, tracks[0]);
 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
 {
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
     {
         mCompleted++;
         mp.reset();
         if (mCompleted < tracks.length) 
         {
             try
             {
                 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(tracks[mCompleted]);
                 if (afd != null) 
                 {
                     mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                     afd.close();
                     mp.prepare();
                     mp.start();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex) 
             {
                ex.printStackTrace();
             }

         } 
         else if (mCompleted>=tracks.length) 
         {
             mCompleted =0;
             try
             {
                 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(tracks[mCompleted]);
                 if (afd != null) 
                 {
                     mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                     afd.close();
                     mp.prepare();
                     mp.start();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex) 
             {
                ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         else
         {
             mCompleted=0;
              mp.release();
              mp = null;
         }

     }
 });

 mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be easier to create an array of MediaPlayers, given you have only 3 of them. You should start only the first and set onCompletionListeners, where you'll start the next player. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good idea. I will work on this now and let you know how it works

Comment: This is what i came up with `MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[0]);MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[1]);MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[2]);
final MediaPlayer [] mediaMp = {mp1, mp2, mp3};
mediaMp[0].start();mediaMp[0].setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){@Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {mediaMp[1].start();
mediaMp[1].setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
mediaMp[2].start();}`. the thing is that it works but there's got to be a shorter way

Answer (score 0):

```
 int flag=0;
 int track; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    NextSongOnline()
    //here in my code i keept all sogns in araayList<> and by using mySongs i am parsing the arraylist that intented from another activity. 
    //mySongs = (ArrayList) bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
}


public void NextSongOnLine(){
    if (flag == 0){
        track = position;
    }
    flag = 1;
    if (track == position){
        position = ((position + 1)%mySongs.size());
        Uri uri3 = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
        myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri3);

        sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().toString();
        songTitle.setText(sname);

        myMediaPlayer.start();
        seekBar.setMax(myMediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);

        //set End time of music
        endTimeText.setText(createTimerLabel(myMediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000));

    }
    track++;
    myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        // after one song completion this override method will be called with next position of song which is holding the counter "track". and that's how the loop will be continuing. 
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            NextSongOnLine();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Auto Playing Next Song",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.