# How to play media files automatically one after another?

Tags: android

If I have a list of songs in an array list and I want to play the songs automatically one by one sequentially. How can I do that ?

Currently my player plays a song and plays the next one only after I press next button. I want to remove this requirement of pressing the next button.

Comment: please provide some code here so anyone can help you.

Comment: What you are actually doing provide the code where you start playing the song ?

Answer (score 4):

`MediaPlayer` class have one method **[setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29)** you can use that like this,

```
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int count =0;
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            count++;
            if(ListOfSongs.length<count)
                // play song from list
            else
                // either set counter to 0 and start again or say end of list

        }
    });
```

---

Found **[one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362030/for-loop-using-a-raw-music-array-android)** on SO that can be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MediaPlayer.onCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) to listen to the event when a track ends, so that you can play the next one

```
player.setDataSource(path);
player.prepare();
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.stop();

            // play next audio file

        }

    });
player.start();
```