# Playing songs one after another in Android(Java)

Tags: java, android

I want to play songs one after another in my music player app. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291659/how-to-play-media-files-automatically-one-after-another) but my music player plays the next song only once. After that it stops. For example, it's playing Song A, then it'll play next Song B, but after song B it won't play Song C.

Here is my code:

OnCompleteListener:

```
//mp is MediaPlayer object, al is ArrayList of songs and their ids(R.raw.song), song_no is the index of the song in al
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                song_no = (song_no +1) % al.size();
                playSong();
            }
        });
```

I have the same code for "next" button which works perfectly, even after reaching the end of list it loops back.
playSong function:

```
public void playSong()
    {
        song = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + al.get(song_no).id());
        try
        {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("playSong", e.toString();
        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), song);

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried removing `mp.reset()`, `mp.release()` and `mp = null` but it still played the next song only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a [Queue](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue) data structure, hopefully is gonna be easier to handle than keeping track of indexes.
Your `al` variable would store a queue of songs to play, in your `onCompletion` method you can call a `playNextSong()` method that handles the queue using `poll()` or `remove()` to get the next song and play until the queue is empty.

If you want to keep your ArrayList, Try debugging your `song_no` and `song` variables to narrow down if the problem is in the song order logic or the MediaPlayer usage.

Comment: If I use a queue, I'll lost the song id after playing it once with either `remove()` or `poll()`. I don't want to do that.I tried checking the song number when the listener is called but I found out that the listener is called only once.

Comment: You do null the MediaPlayer variable in your `playSong()` method, where is `mp.setOnCompletionListener` called? You might need to set it again after you recreated the mp. Do you really need to recreate it everytime?

Comment: Yeah that seemed to be the issue. I need to call `mp.setOnCompleteListener()` after `mp.setDataSource()`. It got fixed after that. Thanks!