# All sound not loaded in array

Tags: android

I have made app. Here i used viewpager two swipe 9 images & accordingly i have loaded 9 sounds but it only plays 8 sounds so when i swipe previous page the sound is not match according to the image. here is my code..

```
package com.android.learning_numbers;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Numbers extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
         ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      //   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(change);
         }



     private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

         private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,};


         private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,};

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
         return mImages.length;
           }

         @Override
         public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
         return view == ((ImageView) object);
         }

         @Override
         public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Numbers.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding =context.getResources().  
            getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0); 
            if(position>=1){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[position-1]);
            mp.start();
            }
           // Log.v("Testing", "Ok");
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page Changing", 5000).show();
            return imageView;
            }

        @Override
         public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
           ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
         }
     }
     }
```

Comment: position might be beginning from 0, hence it plays only 8 and not nine, since your condition reads position >= 1

Comment: @ Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille how do i rectify this??

Comment: could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362219/2683275) help ??

Comment: also the getView method will be called 8 times only so then if you depend on the position, it will only be called 8 times. Probably change where you are trying to play the records from, atleast not in the getView method @SuRaj Prince